# warning of duplicate item while uploading file in document library

Tags: document-library, error, custom-form, file-upload

I have a standard document library. I want to prompt the user if file name already exists in document library. I want this Friendly Error (with custom error text) on "Upload Document" form when when user clicks 'OK' button. I don't want to show default SharePoint Error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a List Item Receiver (Synchronous).

> More specific "Item Adding" event receiver, where you can get the
>   current file name & check it against the existing items & show a
>   message.

UPDATE:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
            if (CheckIfExisting()) //this is where you call yout private method to check file names
            {
                try
                {
            properties.Cancel = true;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = "Please choose some other name.";
                }
                catch (InvalidCreatorIdException ex)
                {
                    properties.Cancel = true;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
                    properties.InvalidateListItem();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can identify duplicate in event receiver but I need to show message in UI. Is it possible that Event throws an message to UI.

Comment: Use below code: public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    if (CheckIfExisting()) //this is custom method {
    try
    {
 properties.Cancel = true;
         properties.ErrorMessage = "Please choose some other name.";
    }
    catch (InvalidCreatorIdException ex)
    {
         properties.Cancel = true;
         properties.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
         properties.InvalidateListItem();
         throw;
    }
  }
}