# Modifying error messages SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

When we drag/drop an .exe file or a file with long name (more than 128 characters) to the SharePoint library, we get the below error:

[image]

[image]
Can we modify these error messages? I need to change the text so that it can make more sense to the user like instead of 'The following files have been blocked' it should say 'You can not upload this file because the extension is blocked by administrator' and for long file name it should say 'You can not upload file with the name having more than 128 characters'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB solution for this. Consider using Event Receiver to customize the error message.

See a few samples here:

[Create custom error page for SharePoint event receiver.](https://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-custom-error-page-for-sharepoint-event-receiver/comment-page-1/)

[warning of duplicate item while uploading file in document library.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66637/warning-of-duplicate-item-while-uploading-file-in-document-library)